# Magento 2 displays price VAT excluded for non logged in user

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-class

I have a problem with my magento 2.1.4
I set up tax ruke for the normal user (19%). The price I entered in the admin are VAT included.
I want to display by default that price.
When a user log in, both prices work fine as you can see :

[image]

But a non logged in user sees only VAT excluded price !!! as you can see:

[image]

**Here is my TAX configuration**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the tax class of the customer group "NOT LOGGED IN" is the same as the logged in customer group.

When both groups have the same tax class, the prices should be the same.

Comment: Yes both customer group have same tax class but still it showing VAT excluded price for non logged in user. Please advice